# forEach loop keeps appending to first child element only

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm running a `forEach` loop for an API that will create a new div for each result with some html appended inside it. While the data is being retrieved, it appends only to the first div created. I'm trying to ensure each set of text ends up in each individual div. Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?

```html
app.displayResults = (arrayOfObjects) => {
  arrayOfObjects.forEach((Object) =>{
    
    const number = Object.house_number;
    const address = Object.street_name;
    const zipCode = Object.zip_code;
    const borough = Object.borough;
    const date = Object.inspection_date;
    const initial = Object.inspection_type;
    const iResult = Object.result;
  
    const resultContainer = document.createElement("div");
    resultContainer.classList.add('resultContainer');
    document.querySelector('.inspectionResults').append(resultContainer); 
    
    const innerHTML = `
    <p class = "recordDetails"> ADDRESS: ${number}${address}</p>
    <p class = "recordDetails"> DATE: ${date}</p>
    <p class = "recordDetails"> BOROUGH: ${borough}</p>`

    const record = document.createElement("div");
    record.classList.add('record');
    record.innerHTML = `${innerHTML}`

    document.querySelector(".resultContainer").append(record)
  })
}
```

Comment: FYI, `Object` is a predefined variable in JS, so change that variable name to something else.

Comment: because `document.querySelector` will always select the first matching element - try `resultContainer.append(record)` since you have that variable that contains the element you wish to append to

Comment: @code is there a way get around that?

Comment: Simply change the variable name to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line of your `forEach` callback, you're querying the first `.resultContainer` element instead of the one you've created before. Instead of immediately appending that div to the DOM, append your `record` to `resultContainer`, *then* append only `resultContainer` to the DOM, like this (I've changed `Object` to `obj` because `Object` is already defined):

```js
app.displayResults = (arrayOfObjects) => {
  arrayOfObjects.forEach((obj) =>{
    const number = obj.house_number;
    const address = obj.street_name;
    const zipCode = obj.zip_code;
    const borough = obj.borough;
    const date = obj.inspection_date;
    const initial = obj.inspection_type;
    const iResult = obj.result;
  
    const resultContainer = document.createElement("div");
    resultContainer.classList.add('resultContainer');
    
    const innerHTML = `
    <p class = "recordDetails"> ADDRESS: ${number}${address}</p>
    <p class = "recordDetails"> DATE: ${date}</p>
    <p class = "recordDetails"> BOROUGH: ${borough}</p>`

    const record = document.createElement("div");
    record.classList.add('record');
    record.innerHTML = `${innerHTML}`

    resultContainer.appendChild(record); // instead of directly appending record to document append it to the container, then append the container to the document
    document.querySelector('.inspectionResults').append(resultContainer); 
  })
}
```

Comment: @confusedCoder great! Hope it solved your problem. If it does, could you also mark the answer as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: @confusedCoder why not accept it?

Answer (score 1):

```html
app.displayResults = (arrayOfObjects) => {
  arrayOfObjects.forEach((obj) =>{
    /*
    const number = Object.house_number;
    const address = Object.street_name;
    const zipCode = Object.zip_code;
    const borough = Object.borough;
    const date = Object.inspection_date;
    const initial = Object.inspection_type;
    const iResult = Object.result;
    */
    // Destructuring Assignment maybe better here
    const { house_number : number, 
           street_name : address, 
           zip_code : zipCode,
           borough,
           inspection_date : date,
           inspection_type : initial,
           result : iResult } = obj
  
    const resultContainer = document.createElement("div");
    resultContainer.classList.add('resultContainer');

    // below is the problem, you appended several divs with the class name 'resultContainer', every time you query, there were a array of it, and you always got the first.
    // document.querySelector('.inspectionResults').append(resultContainer); 
    
    const innerHTML = `
    <p class = "recordDetails"> ADDRESS: ${number}${address}</p>
    <p class = "recordDetails"> DATE: ${date}</p>
    <p class = "recordDetails"> BOROUGH: ${borough}</p>`

    const record = document.createElement("div");
    record.classList.add('record');
    record.innerHTML = innerHTML

    // here just append to the exact div you created above
    resultContainer.append(record)
    // then append the container which contains the content you expected to the documment
    document.querySelector('.inspectionResults').append(resultContainer);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an identifier?

```
terms.setAttribute(‘id’,‘para-1’);
```